# Does Time Capsule automatically backup to the cloud?

Tags: mac, backup, time-capsule

When I purchased my Time Capsule, I was told that it provides two terabytes of storage on the actual capsule and two on "the cloud". Does this happen automatically or do I have to set up something different?

Also, how do I access this?

Comment: Go back to the store and have them show you how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AirPort Time Capsules do not come with any cloud-based storage. They are an entirely network-local backup and storage device. Whomever told you it it had storage "on the cloud" was not being truthful. You can see [the full specs for the AirPort Time Capsule](https://www.apple.com/airport-time-capsule/) on Apple's web page. As you will see: there is no mention of any cloud-based storage at all on that page.